# Primefaces FileUpload Event is not triggered if there are multiple filters in web.xml

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, servlet-filters

I have a web.xml file with two filters PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter & loggedInFilter. If I comment loggedInFilter then FileUpload filter works perfectly fine & FileUploadEvent is triggered. Incase I have keep both the filters in web.xml then FileUpoadFilter is not triggered. Below is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>loggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.web.filter.loggedInFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>*.xhtml</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried to include dispatcher also in PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter filter-mapping because the another filter i.e. loggedInFilter in application runs before the PrimeFaces file upload filter but it doesn't help.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can someone suggest me what needs to be done as I need to keep both the filters in web.xml?

Comment: So your `loggedInFilter` is blocking file upload requests somehow. It's really hard to answer the question as `loggedInFilter` seems to be a homegrown filter and its source code is nowhere visible, so no one can point out the code mistake in that filter.

Comment: @BalusC Correct loggedInFilter is a homegrown filter. I can't put the code as its quite lengthy piece and available only on client machine. I have identified that  if I put breakpoint on FileUploadFilter.doFilter() and FileUploadRender.decode(), they are working fine but the FileUploadEvent defined in my View class is not called, the debugger point never hit my view class.

Comment: Just post code in MCVE flavor. Surely not the entire code snippet is as one whole unit responsible for the misbehavior. Just start off with most minimal line, `chain.doFilter(request, response)`, which is always guaranteed to work. Then add from original source code each time one more line until it starts to misbehave. Logically, the last added line is the cause of the problem. Finally reframe the question to something like "When I add this line [xxx] to my custom filter, the PrimeFaces file upload filter stops working, how is this caused and how can I solve it?", which is a perfect question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to resolve the problem, There was no issue with loggedInfilter but there was issue with some dependencies in pom.xml file which were creating problem for fileUploadFilter to be triggered. I have corrected the dependencies & moreover corrected filter-mapping by removing dispatcher.

```
    <filter> 
         <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name> 
         <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class> 
   </filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
         <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name> 
         <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
    </filter-mapping>
```